# How Add HTML and plain text content to new PDF using itext7

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I'm want to add plain text and HTML content to a PDF that I'm creating. I was able to add plain text but not sure how to add HTML content. I'm not sure how to use `pdfHTML` converter  to combine `htmlString1` and `htmlString`2 with plain text.  Here is my code so far:

```
public ActionResult CreatePdf()
{
    byte[] pdfBytes;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var wri = new PdfWriter(stream))
    using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(wri))
    using (var doc = new Document(pdf))
    {   

        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Working with iText7"));

        doc.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));

        PdfOutline root = pdf.GetOutlines(false);

        foreach (var item in col1)
        {
                        
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(item.Name));
            root.AddOutline(item.Name);
            doc.Add(new AreaBreak());
        }
        
    string htmlString1 = " <!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
        
    string htmlString2 = "<p>My 2nd paragraph</p><hr><p>My 3rd paragraph</p>";
        
        doc.Close();
        doc.Flush();
        pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Checkout https://itextpdf.com/products/convert-html-css-to-pdf-pdfhtml to see how to convert html into pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements` method to convert HTML strings into `iText` elements, and then add these elements to your PDF document

```
public ActionResult CreatePdf()
{
    byte[] pdfBytes;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var wri = new PdfWriter(stream))
    using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(wri))
    using (var doc = new Document(pdf))
    {   
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Working with iText7"));
        doc.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));

    
        foreach (var item in col1)
        {
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(item.Name));
            PdfOutline root = pdf.GetOutlines(false);
            root.AddOutline(item.Name);
            doc.Add(new AreaBreak());
        }
        
        
        string htmlString1 = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
        List<IElement> elements1 = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlString1);
        foreach (var element in elements1)
        {
            doc.Add(element);
        }

        string htmlString2 = "<p>My 2nd paragraph</p><hr><p>My 3rd paragraph</p>";
        List<IElement> elements2 = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlString2);
        foreach (var element in elements2)
        {
            doc.Add(element);
        }

        doc.Close();
        doc.Flush();
        pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: I had to make a small to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string htmlString1 = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</ h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
    List<IElement> elements1 = (List<IElement>)HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlString1);
    foreach (var element in elements1)
    {
      doc.Add((IBlockElement)element);
    }

    string htmlString2 = "<p>My 2nd paragraph</p><hr><p>My 3rd paragraph</p>";
    List<IElement> elements2 = (List<IElement>)HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlString2);
    foreach (var element in elements2)
    {
       doc.Add((IBlockElement)element);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**